# Borrar y Volver a Generar BD

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Tengo una base de datos en android, en la cual por medio de un botón o algo necesito que el usuario pueda eliminar todos los datos, todas las tablas... Absolutamente todo y que automáticamente se vuelvan a generar las tablas ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Esta es mi clase SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Constructor
public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Create table artics(id integer primary key autoincrement, codigo TEXT, descripcion TEXT, pcosto real, precio1 real, precio2 real, precio3 real, precio4 real, idgrupo TEXT, existencia real, codigoa, codsat TEXT, notas TEXT, img BLOOB, idmovil TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("Create table client(id integer primary key autoincrement, codigo TEXT, nombre TEXT, direccion TEXT, noexterior TEXT, nointerior TEXT, colonia TEXT, poblacion TEXT, codigopostal TEXT, rfc TEXT, estado TEXT, diascred INTEGER, limite REAL, telefono1 INTEGER, telefono2 INTEGER, saldo REAL, saldovencido REAL, maxdscto REAL, lista TEXT, email TEXT, comercial TEXT, idmovil TEXT, id_agente TEXT, nombre_agente TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO client(id, codigo, nombre) VALUES (9999, 'VAPEG', 'VENTA AL PUBLICO EN GENERAL')");
    db.execSQL("Create table empresa(id integer primary key autoincrement, nombre TEXT, direccion TEXT, telefono TEXT, correo TEXT, web TEXT, rfc TEXT, logo TXT, contacto TXT, nocd INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("Create table datos(id integer primary key autoincrement, nocd Integer, nolicencia TEXT, fechaVence TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("Create table pedidos(id integer primary key autoincrement, no_pedido integer, fecha TEXT, cod_liente TEXT, id_cliente INTEGER, nombre_cliente TEXT, subtotal REAL, iva REAL, total REAL, letra TEXT, folio INTEGER, estatus TEXT, img TEXT, firma TEXT, notas TEXT, notasimg TEXT, tdoc TEXT, seleccionado TEXT, idmovil TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("Create table pedidoartic(id integer primary key autoincrement, no_pedido TEXT, id_articulo INTEGER, codigo_articulo TEXT, descripcion TEXT, cantidad REAL, p_venta REAL, importe REAL, impuesto REAL, estatus TEXT, notas TEXT, seleccionado TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("Create table consecutivo(id integer primary key autoincrement, folio_pedido integer)");
    db.execSQL("Insert into consecutivo (folio_pedido) values (0)");
    db.execSQL("Create table configuraciones(id integer primary key autoincrement, impresora TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO configuraciones(impresora) VALUES (null)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 3) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE pedidos ADD COLUMN tdoc TEXT");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE pedidos ADD COLUMN seleccionado TEXT");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 4) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE pedidoartic ADD COLUMN seleccionado TEXT");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 5) {
        db.execSQL("Create table configuraciones(id integer primary key autoincrement, impresora TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO configuraciones(impresora) VALUES (null)");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 6) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE artics ADD COLUMN idmovil TEXT");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE client ADD COLUMN idmovil TEXT");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE pedidos ADD COLUMN idmovil TEXT");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 7) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE empresa ADD COLUMN nocd INTEGER");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 8){
        db.execSQL("Create table datos(id integer primary key autoincrement, nocd Integer, nolicencia TEXT, fechaVence TEXT)");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 9) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE client ADD COLUMN saldovencido REAL");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE client ADD COLUMN maxdscto REAL");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: las tablas no se pueden eliminar pero si todos los datos (filas) de las tablas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer para este caso es borrar las tablas, mostrare un ejemplo del como se hace:

Suponiendo que tenemos las siguientes constantes:

```
//DB
public static final String DB = "bdlist.db";

//TABLE
public static final String TableList = "listas";

//CREATE_TABLE
public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_LISTA = "CREATE TABLE " + TableList + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NOMBRE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_PERSONAS + " INT," +
            COLUMN_DESCRIPCION + " TEXT," + COLUMN_CARACTERISTICAS + " TEXT," + COLUMN_IMAGEN + " TEXT," +
COLUMN_FAV + " INT" + ");";

//DELETE TABLE
public static final String SQL_DELETE = "DROP TABLE " + TableList;
```

**Las usarías en tu `Helper` de esta manera:**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DB, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_LISTA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo se elimina la version actual de la tabla y la crea de nuevo, con este ejemplo puedes darte una idea de como resolver de otra forma. Saludos.